# How to take care of one's brain?

Tags: practical-islam, sunnah

We have been ordered to take care of our bodies because they are given to us by Allah and we shall return them (after death) in the best shape possible. We do sports, work out, swim, run, etc., and that aligns with what Allah has ordered us regarding this topic.

Now in the same context. What methods/strategies are there (in Quran or sunnah) that motivate or describe to the Muslims or to the humanity in general why and how to take care of one's own brain?

I am a software engineer and my brain is my most valuable asset. I have been through so many discussions but none of them came from Islamic background or view point. I am convinced that Islam is a way of life that has answers for everything we might encounter, but don't seem to figure this one yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Brother there may not be specific verses or hadiths that tell us "do this and that to take care of your brain", but we believe Islam is not just a religion, but a way of life, so to follow the rulings of islam is to live life perfectly. This means your brain is automatically taken care of, along with everything else when you take care of your religion. But to give you a heads up, our daily prayer in itself provides you with so many physical, spiritual and mental benefits. 
The placement of the forehead upon the ground causes an increased blood supply to the brain and has been cited as having a good effect upon memory, vision, hearing, concentration, and other cognitive abilities. A few websites with interesting information on the benefits of prayer are included below. We however dont pray for these benefits. We pray because as god instructed us to do so, and these benefits come as extra bonuses. 
Islam also doesnt encourage boxing as a sport because it causes direct damage to the brain, and anything that intoxicates the body is not allowed, especially those that intoxify the brain. theses are just a few examples.

http://www.islamreligion.com/articles/10272/wisdom-behind-postures-and-phrases-of-prayer-part-1-of-2/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mlGBKtIz3_g

http://www.islamreligion.com/articles/10272/wisdom-behind-postures-and-phrases-of-prayer-part-1-of-2/

Comment: +1 for great answer

Answer (score 3):

In the name of God, the Most Gracious, the Most Merciful.

"Tashanna Chamma" has already a great answer, but I wanna add something else, that might be helpful for you too.

I think the best way to take care of your brain, is to take care of your heart first. As mentioned in the following hadith:

> An-Nu`man ibn Bashir (may Allah be pleased with him) narrated that Prophet Muhammad (peace and blessings be upon him) said, "Beware! There is a piece of flesh in the body, if it becomes good (i.e., reformed), **the whole body becomes good**, but if it gets spoilt, the whole body gets spoilt, **and that is the heart**." (Al-Bukhari)

This tells us that if we take care of our heart (not our physical heart alone, but especially our spiritual heart), by gaining more knowledge of Islam (through Qur'an, Sunnah, or just good deeds in general), and things like that, then we take care of our **whole** body.

I hope this helps. Allah knows best.

Peace be unto you.

Comment: I have known this Hadith for many years I was just oblivious about it! +1 for the reminder